# Getting a proper stream result with with native annotated queries?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am currently using hibernate 5.0.7 and due to limitations in HQL queries (mainly the lack of a TOP or LIMIT ability) I have come to the point where I am trying to implement a native SQL query. 
Due to the way that our repositories are wired up as spring beans from interfaces we are currently using a combination of annotated queries and functional queries to obtain data.

A sample of my query is as follows

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM some_table where (id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true)
Stream<MyObject> getMyObjectByIds(String userId);
```

however; my real query is more complex and makes use of GroupBy (something functional queries don't seem to have) and Top (something that direct HQL queries don't seem to have)

All of the tables and items in our database are mapped entities, and all of the data that is currently in the database has been put there by these hibernate entities to begin with. Now, when I run my query I actually get a result back that looks very much like it should be my data I end up getting back

```
{2, 3, 5, Whatever, null}
```

and in my data base I have the exact some row values

```
{2, 3, 5, Whatever, NULL}
```

however, when I try to access the stream object that I have my function type set as from my native query I end up with the error

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [com.myorg.models.MyObject] for value '{2, 3, 5, Whatever, null}'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [com.myorg.models.MyObject]
```

Now from what I've looked up people seem to suggest that there is an SqlResultSetMapping mapping that isn't in place somewhere, and if I look on my entity there is indeed no such mapping

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "MyObject.withChildren",
    attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "objectChildren")
)
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "object_table", schema = "my_table")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
```

I actually even looked some stuff up and tried to implement a mapping

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "ObjectMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = MyObject.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "childId", column = "child_id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "someNumber", column = "some_numbur"),
                @FieldResult(name = "someString", column = "some_string"),
                @FieldResult(name = "someNullableType", column = "null_type_column")
            }
        )
    }
)
```

and stuck on my entity class, but I really don't even know how/why/if this is necessary, and worse it didn't even work. Granted that this is a rather obfuscated description of my code/problem is there something simple I'm missing, or does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

I am thankful for any and all help people are willing to provide!

Comment: Could be column naming issue. Check that result query column names are exactly named. E.g. if you use just `count(*)` add `count(*) as some_number`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've managed to get this working by attaching a `@NamedNativeQuery` to my entity object itself

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
name = "MyEntity.complexSqlQuery",
query = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM my_table WHERE (my_table.id = ?1)",
resultClass = MyEntity.class
```

and then adding

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> complexSqlQuery(String whatever);
```

to my interface style repository. I don't know if this is ideal as it seems like dumping a crap load of queries onto the entity itself isn't exactly best practice, and I was really hoping for some annotated tag I could just throw on the query already existing in my repository (it seems like the resultClass is exactly what the `@Query` annotation **needs** to support this in my case), but it seems no such option exists.

None the less, I did get this solved, just not necessarily in the way I liked. 
If anyone has some insight into what I may have missed, I would be very open to hear it, otherwise this is the solution I have come up with until then.